# How can I apply multilevel numbering only to some headings in MS Word and not all headings of a level?

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, table-of-contents, list, numbering

I would like to apply multilevel numbering of headings in Microsoft Word, but only for some of the headings of Level 1, but not for all of the headings. At the moment I defined the headings as level 1 or level 2 using "Styles". Afterwards I click on "create multilevel list". This results in numbering of all Headings level 1 consecutively from 1 onward as displayed below

Example 1

[image: Example 1 screenshot]

But I actually would like to only number the Headings level 1 from the 3rd to the 5th Heading level 1 (C-E), as shown below. The 1st, 2nd, 6th and 7th Heading level 1 should not get numbered. How can I achieve this with MS Word?

Example 2

[image]

Comment: Cross-posted at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-can-i-apply-multilevel-numbering-only-to-some/0b818468-a9f4-49d0-aae2-3c5096feb94e For cross-posting etiquette, please read: A Message to Forum Cross-Posters https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! This is a very good point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Set up your Numbering attached to Styles as set forth in [Shauna Kelly's Page](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html).

Have a separate, level 1 style to use for your non-numbered headings.

Using Shauna's method, each level of the multi-level list is associated with an existing paragraph style. You apply the numbering by applying the style, not by using the numbering buttons on the Home tab. You can have a separate level 1 heading that is not associated with your multilevel list but which is otherwise formatted the same.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try this!

Comment: Update: I followed the instructions from "Shauna Kelly's Page" and it worked perfectly, thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome.