# My Multilevel list indents aren't being applied to new chapter headings until I force them

Tags: microsoft-word

I created a new Multilevel list. It indents everything that I highlight and force perfectly. But then whenever I create a new chapter the heading indent is way off. I tried creating a style from [Shuana Kelly's page](https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html) But it did the same thing.  And this [How can I apply multilevel numbering only to some headings in MS Word and not all headings of a level](https://superuser.com/questions/1646164/how-can-i-apply-multilevel-numbering-only-to-some-headings-in-ms-word-and-not-al) had no info I could use.

The pic displays how I have to force the indent by opening that menu then press 'OK' each time.  See how "Another new ..." is indented differently and I've selected it to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Can you attach a link to a problem document on OneDrive or DropBox in your question? ------ The answer in the questiion you linked is mine. If you have your numbered headings attached to styles as set forth in Shauna Kelly's page, they should be maintained. You need to insert your numbering by using the style, not by using the buttons on the ribbon.  I would be happy to look at a problem document.

Comment: Does this happen with a brand new document as well, or specifically the one you are working on right now?